# Creating a light that follows the player

Tags: unity, lighting

How do I create a point light that follows the player character when they walk around? The light should shine on the player and not on a fixed point.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you mean by "reproduced"? Please try again to explain what it is you want to do and what's currently not working about it. Edit the question with this information.

Comment: In the sense: in the meantime, if you walk the point light it sheds light where you go and not at a fixed point

Comment: You want the light to follow the player?

Comment: @Byte56: Yes, for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to do this, is to make the light a child of the character. Position the light where you want it to be in relation to the player, then in the Hierarchy view, drag the light so that it becomes a child of the player.

[image]

Now when the player is moved, all of its children are moved as well (including the light).

---

Another option is to use one of the built in scripts called "Smooth Follow". On your light object, in the Inspector, click on the Add Component button.

[image]

Find the "Smooth Follow" script and add it to the light.

Then set the player as the follow target:

[image]

Do that by dragging the player object from the Hierarchy view and dropping it on the Target (Empty) variable.

Now the light object will follow the player with a little bit of smoothing.

Comment: Dont find Smooth Follow

Comment: Check under the camera controls. If it's still not there, make sure you imported it when you created the project.